# Restore Playlists

Tags: music, mp3

I carefully crafted music playlists in the "Play Music" app on my Android.

I deleted some songs from my library, but the song titles still appeared in my playlists.

Now the titles are gone, and I need the proper tracklisting for these playlists. Please help.

How do I recover the songs, or at least the titles?